# Dividir e buscar mensagens por mais antigas e recentes

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tenho uma **tabela**. Nela a 4 **colunas**
`ID` com alto incremento,
`id_user1` quer seria o id do usuário que enviou a mensagem,
 
`id_user2` quer seria o id do usuário que recebeu e
`mensagem` a que recebe a mensagem enviada por `id_user1` para `id_user2`.

Há alguma forma de buscar os mais recentes para uma lista de mensagens?
Digo, temos o **Whatsapp** e várias outras aplicações que seguem o mesmo sistema da lista de mensagem, onde vão subindo de acordo com a mais recente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que da pra fazer com um `DESC`, mas queria algo dinâmico que mostra-se em tempo real e que ficasse separado por ide como os aplicativos e não o ID 1 agora e depois o ID 1 novamente na 4 ou 5 e etc... cada um separado e sem mostrar o mesmo `id_user1` novamente..

Entenderam?

Comment: Adicione um campo na sua tabela com a data de envio. Depois no `checarPorNovasMensagens.php` coloque um argumento informando o ultimo horário em que uma mensagem foi recebida. Na hora de dar `select` basta selecionar todas mensagens cujo horário de envio seja mais recente que o da ultima mensagem recebida. Alternativamente, você pode selecionar o último horário que a mensagem foi enviada à  um campo da sua tabela de usuários.

Comment: aconselho usar UTC e converter a timezone depois, para prevenir dores de cabeça!

Comment: mas o "order by data desc" seria só um filtro para ordenar os registros em ordem cronológica decrescente, de forma que dentro de cada registro você poderá implementar da forma que desejar, contendo, ou não informações como ID e afins.

Comment: não sei de nada, mas explica uma coisa, como é que faz p/ meu whattssap aparecer "coisando..." ao invés de escrevendo....kkkkkkk

Answer (score 1):

Adicionando uma coluna na sua tabela, você poderá ordenar à vontade usando o `SELECT`, sem mexer mesmo com cada recorde na tabela. Por exemplo:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD data_enviada DATETIME;
```

Depois, poderia escrever uma consulta assim:

```sql
SELECT
   ID,
   id_user1,
   id_user2,
   id_mensagem
FROM
   tabela
ORDER BY
  data_enviada
```

Assim está ordenado pela data, mas não necessáriamente *mostra* a data.